# specific logger for levels

Tags: log4j

I am using log4j for logging. I have a scenario where I have to use seperate logging for different severity. For example, for package foo I have to print messages with severity ERROR in the console whereas I have to print messages with severity WARN in log file. How can I configure my log4j.xml for the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use LevelMatchFilter for your task. Also you should not forget to use another filter - DenyAllFilter - as the last filter in the chain of filters.

Your log4j.xml will look like this:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout" />
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
            <param name="LevelToMatch" value="ERROR" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter" />     
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="error.log" /> 
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout" />
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
            <param name="LevelToMatch" value="WARN" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter" />     
    </appender>

    <logger name="foo">
         <level value="WARN" />
         <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
         <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </logger>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Why we should use `DenyAllFilter`?

Comment: @Tariq In short: because LevelMatchFilter will remain NEUTRAL if the level of the event will not match the value of parameter LevelToMatch. So to deny all the events that LevelMatchFilter will not accept (in our case because AcceptOnMatch = true) we need DenyAllFilter.