# logging pattern for specyfic package

Tags: xml, logging, log4j, log4j2

Hi im trying to improve logging on my server (log4j2), all my packages are using one common config file which has a some global pattern like this:

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="patternLayout1"> some pattern </Property>
    <Property name="patternLayout2"> other pattern </Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="GENERAL_SYNC_CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${patternLayout1}"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>

<!-- some configuration is below -->

</Appenders>
```

How can configure int this file that one/some of packages uses `patternLayout2` for logging instead of `patternLayout1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12203954/7445344) for you. You can define `category` for different packages, and inside them you can define `appender-ref` what is / are the reference of your appender(s). You can read about it in the official [doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html).

I hope it helps. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="pattern1" value="PATTERN1: -> %msg%n"/>
        <Property name="pattern2" value="PATTERN2: -> %msg%n"/>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console1">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern1}"/>
        </Console>
        <Console name="console2">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern2}"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="your.package" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console2"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="console1"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```